# Is it possible to combine groups of programs in the start menu, due to overcrowding

Tags: windows, start-menu

I'm running Windows XP Home Edition..Heres's my dilemma. When I click Start > All Programs, I have so many programs installed I'm almost at the end of the fourth row. I don't want to cross that barrier of coming to the end of that row. Is there a way to combine "Groups". For instance, make a new Group called "DVD Programs" and then put all my DVD group programs in there? That would free up about 6 slots right there. Say another group called "Utilities" and do the same. If windows itself won't do the job, maybe a stand alone piece of software?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this via Windows Explorer, but it depends on where the shortcuts are and who can access the program.  To edit the Start Menu for shortcuts that are only visible to your profile, go to `C:\Documents and Settings\yourusername\Start Menu\Programs`. For all users (including your profile) go to `C:\Documents and Settings\All Users\Start Menu\Programs`.

You can create folders and move shortcuts around to your liking. This is the biggest customization I do on a new machine after I've installed everything because I hate how large the Start Menu becomes.

Comment: Once you start moving product icons, you'll need an uninstaller like Revo to totally uninstall products - the product's uninstaller will look in vain for the icons where they were supposed to be (but aren't any more).

Comment: Rather then going to find the start menu folder, simply right click the start button and choose > Explore. This opens Explorer with your profile already open to the Start Menu folder.
Choosing Explore All Users does the same for the All Users folder, naturally.
You may have to create subfolders in both of these to match each other, depending on what applications you want to have in each. Any folders with identical names are simply merged to display them in the Start menu

Answer (score 0):

Itzoe's suggestions are excellent, but if I may offer another tip, do as google says, search, don't sort! Look at launchy. Once you start using it, you won't be able to give it up!

[Launchy](http://launchy.net/)

Answer (score 0):

I Have the same problem only I have 6 col's and need to adjust again.  All columns are spaced by the longest name of any program you have listed, so rename (shorten)(right click) the long named programs and the column widths will decrease accordingly allowing more columns. When I ran out of room that way, I reduced the print size.  Now I am again out of room and want to combine catagories which is what I am looking for the 'how to' when I came across this post.  Good Luck.